# How to get pop-up when my profile picture is hovered?

Tags: support, users, profile-picture, user-card

In some posts (questions or answers) when you hover the users profile picture under the post, it shows a pop-up with a summary of this user's profile details, like in this picture:

[image]

I would like to know:

- Why doesn't it work for all users?
- Why don't some users get this option while there are users with the
  same reputation that have this kind of option?
- And how can we earn it?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The feature is called the *extended usercard* and is earned with the [*Established User* privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user). Simply get 1.000 points or more.

Not all users with reputation > 1000 have one because they don't have enough text in their *About Me* section, or they explicitly disabled it.

From the privilege help info:

> An expanded usercard is only available if there are at least 28 characters in the "About Me" section of your profile.

and

> If you have a long profile About Me, but don't want there to be an expanded usercard for any reason, you can use the summary comment with an insufficiently long passage to render your profile as "too short" for display. For example, the following will be considered too short.
>
> ```
> <!-- summary: &nbsp; -->
> ```

In your specific case, the text *Software Engineer* is not long enough to warrant a extended usercard.

Comment: Great, I think that's all I needed to know abou it. Thank you!

Comment: Funny, I have a long profile About Me and I want the popup. Only trouble is it gets truncated in the popup. I'm long winded. *sigh*

Comment: @Sukima In that case, you can add a summary for the portion you want to show in the popup: `<!-- summary: this is summary about me that is less than 5 lines long -->`